# How can I build a XML Structure within another XML Structure?

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I'm creating a basic outline of a xml structure inside one function and then passing in the data that's used to create the inner/data parts of the xml into another function. How can I add (or append) to the different xml structures using coldfusion. I'm not all too familiar to using xml or coldfusion either, and the cf docs don't really help all too much.

This is a simplified version of what I got going on but it illustrates the point:

```
<cffunction  name="getSomeXML" access="private">
    <cfargument  name="qryToGetData" type="query">

    <cfset var LOCAL = StructNew()>
    <cfsavecontent  variable="LOCAL.XML"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Types>
            <cfoutput query="qryToGetData">
                <A><![CDATA[#xmlFormat(qryToGetData.aType)#]]></A>
                <B><![CDATA[#xmlFormat(qryToGetData.bType)#]]></B>
                <C><![CDATA[#xmlFormat(qryToGetData.cType)#]]></C>
                <D><![CDATA[#xmlFormat(qryToGetData.dType)#]]></D>
            </cfoutput>
        </Types>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfset LOCAL = createInnerXML(LOCAL)> <!--- Call Function to Make Inner XML --->
    <cfreturn LOCAL> <!--- Return Complete XML --->
</cffunction>

<cffunction  name="innerXML" access="private">
    <cfargument name="arguments" hint="arguments">

    <cfset var innerXMLSRT = StructNew()>
    <cfsavecontent  variable="innerXMLSRT.XML"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Data>
            <cfoutput>
                #arguments.xmlFeed#
            </cfoutput>
        </Data>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn innerXMLSRT> <!--- Return Complete XML --->
</cffunction>

<!--- OUTPUT: --->
<Types>
    <Data>
        <A></A>
        <B></B>
        <C></C>
        <D></D>
    </Data>
</Types>
```

Comment: Your second function only seems to wrap the XML contents from the first function with a `<Data>` element. Is there a specific reason why you cannot create the wanted XML structure in directly?

Comment: yes, to keep it simple, it's because the inner xml can change and this way it'll keep things easier to build/maintain.

Comment: So you have a container that's always fixed, and a variable part in-between?

Comment: yea, that's a good way to put it

Comment: And the `OUTPUT:` sample is your wanted result? Asking because the way you did it, `<Data>` does not wrap around everything, but is inserted "in the middle" itself.

Comment: oh you're right, it should be that the `<A></A>` and such tags can change, the `<Types>` and `<Data>` would remain the same

Comment: Can you not just remove innerXML() completely and add the <Data> around the <Types>. At the moment you actually have 2 <xml...> tags which is invalid. I know you say above that you want the top couple of tags to stay fixed, but you really won't lose any modularity this way...

Comment: I could but that just defeats the purpose of having a simple, easy way to keep all the 'top tags' that same so that I could have different 'inner tags'.

Comment: I've been wrestling with this for the last good hour or so; let me tell you it's surprisingly difficult. It's not exactly straightforward in most programming languages, owing to how XML documents work in general. But the way ColdFusion represents XML documents internally makes it especially hard. It's not going to be a simple one-liner, that's for sure. Ben Nadel has an article on this topic ([see](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/701-copying-children-from-one-coldfusion-xml-document-to-another.htm)), maybe his `XmlAppend()` function works for you.

Comment: @Tomalak, thank you for the read (and hilarious example Ben used). I'm trying it out now. Please let me know if you think of anything esle

Comment: OK. From @Tomalak answers, I think I now understand want you are trying to do. Are you trying to append the inside of an XML document, whilst keeping the XML that has already been written. If so, I will change my answer?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Ahhhh. I'm with you. I will edit my answer tonight unless @Tomalak has given you an adequate answer...

Comment: Well it's definitely an answer. And one that seems like it'll work, but just like Tomalak had said, it's not actually using xml and it may be impossible to do so with cf and xml and it's really not sustainable and the purpose of what I'm trying to do is make it more sustainable. I'm trying to come up with something using XMLAppend. If you think of something more along those lines, I would be appreciative (or using and sticking with an xml struct / array or cf struct).

Comment: OK. I will give this some thought. I think using xmlSearch, which uses XPATH syntax might help. I will play around with this approach.

Comment: I have no idea where you get that notion from, I'm not saying it's impossible. I'm saying it's more trouble than it's worth, or very close to it. In fact I went out of my way in my answer to say *exactly that* and nothing else.

Comment: You right, my meaning of my message is lost on text so I should have been clearer when I was saying that it's difficult to do and impossible. You certainly provided me with a great (and potentially only) answer and I definitely appreciate the effort you put into it.

Comment: Can I ask whether you are storing this XML in a file?

Comment: It's only for display purposes, the data comes from a db

Comment: OK. Well I have written a function that allows you to choose multiple formats, using Coldfusion XML functions....

Comment: @Ale I have completely re-written my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Effectively you want to insert one XML document into another, at a certain location.

The *correct*, canonical way to do that is this sequence of steps:

1. Create XML documents A (wrapper) and B (data to be inserted)
2. pick (a list of) XML nodes from B to be inserted into A
3. for each such node, *import* it into A
4. for each such imported node, *insert* it into A at the desired location

This rather complex method is necessary since XML nodes cannot freely be moved between different DOM trees. Each node has an "owner document" which cannot change during the lifetime of the node. Creating a physical copy is the only way to get a node into a different document.

In ColdFusion however there is an added complication. It supports some quite convenient syntax for working with XML documents. XML objects behave both like arrays and like structs and work with the related functions, and you can use dot paths like `xml.Data.Foo.XmlAttributes.Bar` directly in your code to read out e.g. an attribute value. This level of convenience comes at a cost - ColdFusion wraps XML nodes into an abstraction layer and thereby hides the underlying, actual node objects, which overall makes it difficult to access the DOM methods that we need for node import and the like.

After digging through ColdFusion's XML internals, I came up with a half-way elegant function:

```
<cffunction name="XmlAppend" returntype="void" output="no">
  <cfargument name="target" type="xml" required="yes">
  <cfargument name="source" type="array" required="yes">

  <cfset var sNode = "">

  <cfloop array="#source#" index="sNode">
    <cfset target.appendChild(
      target.getOwnerDocument().importNode(sNode.cloneNode(true), true)
    )>
  </cfloop>
</cffunction>
```

This function can copy any number of `source` nodes to a `target` node. Since the function modifies the target node in-place, there is no return value.

The crucial part is the call to `.cloneNode()`. The `.importNode()` function cannot handle the ColdFusion XML wrapper object that `sNode` actually is (class: `coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList`, wrapping `org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementNSImpl` and cousins).

There is no way (that I found) to get the underlying XML node object from the wrapper, except through cloning it. So this step is wasteful, but nothing else made `.importNode()` play along.

With these XML documents,

```
<cfxml variable="dataXml">
  <Types>
    <a>aaaa</a>
    <a>bbbb</a>
  </Types>
</cfxml>

<cfxml variable="wrapperXml">
  <Data>
    <some>exsting node</some>
  </Data>
</cfxml>
```

calling would work like this:

```
<!-- all children of /Types into the /Data node -->
<cfset XmlAppend(wrapperXml.Data, dataXml.Types.XmlChildren)>

<!-- same thing, but with XPath and explicit argument names -->
<cfset XmlAppend(
  target: XmlSearch(wrapperXml, '/Data')[1],
  source: XmlSearch(dataXml, '/Types/*')
)>
```

and result in this:

```
<Data>
  <some>exsting node</some>
  <a>aaaa</a>
  <a>bbbb</a>
</Data>
```

This function uses a lot of undocumented API. I've tested it from CF 7 through CF 2016 and it works in all those versions, but you'd still be on your own when you put it into production code and then a future update to ColdFusion breaks it, or when it doesn't work at all in 3rd-party implementations like Railo. Use at your own peril.

For the sake of completeness, Ben Nadel [has also implemented an `XmlAppend` function](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/701-copying-children-from-one-coldfusion-xml-document-to-another.htm).

---

Using only officially supported API, this task cannot be done in a *nice* way in ColdFusion.

The following approach uses only official API, but using regex and string interpolation on XML is not at all what I would call clean:

```
<!-- remove XML declaration if present -->
<cfset var dataXmlStr = REReplace(ToString(dataXml), '^<\?xml[^>]*>', '')>

<cfxml variable="wrapperXml">
    <Data><cfoutput>#dataXmlStr#</cfoutput></Data>
</cfxml>
```

Removing the XML declaration is crucial, because ColdFusion always adds it when we call `ToString()` on an XML object, but it's not legal to have it appear anywhere in an XML document except for once at the very start. Forgetting to remove the XML declaration will result in a parser error in the `<cfxml>`.

Note that `<cfxml>` is effectively the same as `<cfsavecontent>` - it creates a string from its body, but additionally it parses that string into an XML document as a final step.

---

I've measured it and the `importNode`/`appendNode` approach appears to be generally faster than the string interpolation approach. By how much depends on the actual task.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED 02.07.18**

OK. Building on Ben Nadel's AppendXml() function, I have created a custom function for your requirements, which will append to existing nodes, using a pure XML approach.

**Features:**

- This solution uses officially documented Coldfusion functions
- The return value can either be a string or an object
- Input string can either be a fragment or use a prolog

Just change the query column references for new ones, if your column names are different.

```
<cffunction name="AppendXml" returntype="any" output="no" access="private">
  <!---arguments--->
  <cfargument name="query" type="query" required="yes" hint="I output the CDATA">
  <cfargument name="xml" type="any" required="yes" hint="I am the orginal XML text string that requires appending">
  <cfargument name="outputString" type="boolean" required="no" default="true" hint="I output whether the XML is in object or string format">
  <!---local variables--->
  <cfset var local = StructNew()>
  <!---logic--->
  <cfset local.xml = REReplaceNoCase(ToString(arguments.xml),"<\?[^>]*>","")>
  <cfif IsXml(local.xml)>
    <cfset local.xml = XmlParse(local.xml)>
    <cfset ArrayAppend(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren,XmlElemNew(local.xml,"Types"))>
    <cfloop query="arguments.query">
      <cfset ArrayAppend(local.xml.Data.Types[ArrayLen(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren)].XmlChildren,XmlElemNew(local.xml,"A"))>
      <cfset local.xml.Data.Types[ArrayLen(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren)]["A"].XmlCData = xmlFormat("aType")>
      <cfset ArrayAppend(local.xml.Data.Types[ArrayLen(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren)].XmlChildren,XmlElemNew(local.xml,"B"))>
      <cfset local.xml.Data.Types[ArrayLen(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren)]["B"].XmlCData = xmlFormat("bType")>
      <cfset ArrayAppend(local.xml.Data.Types[ArrayLen(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren)].XmlChildren,XmlElemNew(local.xml,"C"))>
      <cfset local.xml.Data.Types[ArrayLen(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren)]["C"].XmlCData = xmlFormat("cType")>
      <cfset ArrayAppend(local.xml.Data.Types[ArrayLen(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren)].XmlChildren,XmlElemNew(local.xml,"D"))>
      <cfset local.xml.Data.Types[ArrayLen(local.xml.Data.XmlChildren)]["D"].XmlCData = xmlFormat("dType")>
    </cfloop>
    <cfif arguments.outputString>
      <cfset local.xml = ToString(local.xml)>
    </cfif>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset local.xml = arguments.xml>
  </cfif>
  <cfreturn local.xml>
</cffunction>

<cfset query = QueryNew("aType,bType,cType,dType")>
<cfset QueryAddRow(query)> 
<cfset QuerySetCell(query,"aType","small")>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query,"bType","medium")>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query,"cType","large")>
<cfset QuerySetCell(query,"dType","extra large")>

<cfsavecontent variable="xml">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Data>
    <Types>
      <A><![CDATA[small]]></A>
      <B><![CDATA[medium]]></B>
      <C><![CDATA[large]]></C>
      <D><![CDATA[extralarge]]></D>
    </Types>
    <Types>
      <A><![CDATA[small]]></A>
      <B><![CDATA[medium]]></B>
      <C><![CDATA[large]]></C>
      <D><![CDATA[extralarge]]></D>
    </Types>
  </Data> 
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset AppendXml = AppendXml(query=query,xml=xml,outputString=false)>

<cfdump var="#AppendXml#" />
```

Comment: I don't quite get `REReplaceNoCase(ToString(arguments.xml),"<[^>]*>","")` - what's the purpose of this replace?

Comment: This is only necessary, if passing an entire XML Document string into the method. Wanted to be safe...

Comment: Yeah, the XML parse fails because calling `ToString()` on an XML document will include the XML declaration (`<?xml ...>`), and inserting that as-is into another XML string will cause a subsequent parser error. Your regex matches the XML declaration, so it works when you pass an XML object. However your `xml` argument is of type `any`, so one could theoretically pass an XML string like `<test>data</test>`. Your regex would then remove the first element, resulting in `data</test>`, and boom, the document blows up again. You want a more specific regex, one that *only* matches the XML declaration.

Comment: But my more general point is that the whole voodoo with `ArrayAppend()` and `XmlElemNew()` is completely useless when half of the work is still being done by serializing XML to string and running regex. The DOM approach is only worth doing when it's done from start to finish. No serializing and parsing in-between and god forbid no regex. When it's not possible to do that (and CF *really* makes it hard), then it's not any better than dealing with strings from start to finish, if that makes sense.

Comment: The code Ben Nadel has posted does the right thing. The only gripe I have with it is that it uses undocumented API. Calling `GetChildNodes` and `GetOwnerDocument` works, but it's not guaranteed to work with other/future versions of CF (or 3rd-party implementations of the ColdFusion language, for that matter).

Comment: Serializing is just one option in my function. The regex is only there to remove the doctype, which CF XML won't parse. I don't use regex anywhere else, so I think your comment about regex is somewhat exaggerating the issue. The OP wants the solution to use CF XML methodology. This is what I  have tried to achieve?

Comment: OK. You have a point about the regex removing the first tag, so I have ammended this, to prevent that.

Comment: I'm not exaggerating. :) If you have to resort to using regex and serializing and re-parsing parts of an XML document *just once* or a thousand times makes no difference in quality. The whole solution immediately becomes tainted. There is no way that using `XmlElemNew()` everywhere else can make up for such a thing. It's all-or-nothing, simple as that.

Comment: I am only serializing at the end. Hardly 'half the work', and this is optional anyway.  This solution allows the OP flexibility in how he wants to work with the data and he stated many times in previous comments that he wants a solution that uses CF XML functions. I am only trying to satisfy these comments.

Comment: So you are saying that a function cannot return data in multiple formats? I disagree.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying.

Comment: Well, this function is meant to allow the OP to receive the appended XML in different formats. From your previous answer, this function is OK, then?

Comment: It is just easier to work with CF XML functions when trying to work with and append to, different XML nodes, especially when using CDATA, if the objective of the function is to return the data in multiple formats. This is the objective of my solution. It maybe that you disagree with the objective. Thats OK...

Comment: I'm not trying to argue with you, I'm basically thinking out loud. My solution is objectively horrible, too. I'd *never* do it that way if the language would leave me any choice. All I'm saying is that one can't mix a good thing (native XML functions, DOM operations) and a bad thing (regex and string interpolation on XML) and still get a good thing in the end. The bad thing still spoils the whole, even if it's done just a little. That's what made me go "screw it, then I can just as well do string operations all the way". That said, CDATA is not even necessary, `XmlFormat()` is sufficient.

Comment: OK. @Tomalak. I apologise for being a little defensive, but I spent quite a bit of time building this solution and words like 'useless' after a hard day in the office, didn't resonate too harmoniously with me. I understand what you are saying about choosing one path or the other, but I guess I just wanted to try and address part of what the OP was asking for. I can see that the OP wants XML string data back, but I thought he might want to manipulate the XML as an object, at some point in the future, because he keeps asking for a solution that uses native XML functions.

Comment: I have spent more hours wrestling with ColdFusion over this than I care to admit, and I'm a bit frustrated myself. I have something that is elegant and sort of works, but it's using all internal undocumented APIs and it's not correct yet on top of that. So even if I crack the last bit and make it correct, I'd *still* not use it in production code because any update to ColdFusion might break it. Overall it boils down to: This task is not possible to do it in a nice way in ColdFusion.

Comment: I think I've got it. I've updated my answer substantially.

Comment: Personally, I would never use undocumented features, so I would go with the regex version.

Comment: Same for me (as I said, it's also the thing that I dislike about Ben Nadel's solution, in addition to the verbosity of the code). But when one goes the "undocumented API" route, one can go it all the way. Just like with going the "string" route all the way. The string version will instantly fall apart when clashing XML namespaces are involved, which is actually pretty scary to me. The third option to explore would be XSLT via `XslTransform()`, with parameters. But no matter how this is approached, there is no truly nice way to do it in CF.

Comment: I have a feeling that the real problem here, is the OP's question. I'm not sure he has given us an accurate brief. Nevertheless, it has been a useful exercise in learning more about CF's XML capabilities.

Comment: Yep... I think the OP *might* be better off ditching the whole "wrapper XML" idea.

Comment: Just out of interest, I thought that the XML prolog declaration was unique in that it uses <?... So, why are you worried about namespace clashing?

Comment: Hm... my initial thought was: When one does `<ns1:doc xmlns:ns1="http://foo">#someXmlString#</ns1:doc>` and then `someXmlString` *also* contains the `ns1` prefix, but with a different namespace URI... But now that I think about more closely, it would still work. It's actually possible that namespace prefixes are redefined in an XML document.

Comment: you're both correct in that my question is, I guess, foolish. I started to implement @CharlesRobertson's answer, however I realized I'd have to change much more than is worth in other sections of my code that touch this functionality. Although I must say that both of you went well beyond my expectations on delivering something 'good/nice with cf' so that's amazing. I'm not a cf developer so your conversations have helped more so than the answers you've provided and I've come out of this with a better understanding.

Comment: I'm currently trying to come up with a 'better' way to accomplish my end goal, not that you both care to hear that (or maybe you do). A solution that involves documented cf and that is sustainable for the future.

Comment: Hey. Thanks @Ale. I'm glad this has been of some use. Yes. I have to say, I was in 2 minds as to whether to use 'local.cdataPrefix', because this is very specific and I guess your Query columns are probably called something different than 'aType' etc. I could just update my answer to remove the inner loop and add the logic for each column. Then you could just replace the column references...

Comment: @Ale That's a fair stance. You could give XSLT a chance, I'd whip that approach up as well if you're still interested.

Comment: @Ale I will update my answer later, and then I will call it day, as far as this question goes...

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm not opposed to seeing what you come up with XSLT. I don't know much about it though, so I'd have to do some of my own research on it as well. and that sounds good @CharlesRobertson!

Comment: @Ale Well, forget the XSLT idea, I've tried, it doesn't work. Your safest bet is probably the "all string" `<wrapper>#contents#</wrapper>` approach, despite its ugliness. It's short and immediately obvious, it follows what CF code typically looks like, it uses only documented API, and all other avenues have been explored by now.

Comment: That's ultimately what I went with. It's fugly, but it works! :)

Comment: @Ale Glad you found your solution. I updated my answer to make it a bit easier to modify...